# Dynamic email box managing with php

Tags: php, email

I need to enable email messaging with website users in this way:

- email is sent to a customer from a user or from a specific task (the sender is task_123435@domain.com)
- when customer replies the email, the website takes the reply and assigns it to the task_123435.

The solution is established in Google groups, many crm systems etc..

What are possible solutions? Also is there a specific name for such a system, so I could find a ready to use solution?

Currently I come up with these options:

- dynamically manage email boxes with php IMAP functions, creating a
  new email box for every user/task/issue I want to tag later. (more
  complicated and reliable)
- Add user/task ID to email subject line and
  then filter replies by that subject. (less complicated and less
  reliable
- any more?

Comment: I have skipped this problem for a while but its facing me again.. As much as I have figured out with some of stakhoverflow members help is receiving email: you can configure your email to be forwarded to one emailbox which you can then easily read, but what about sending out email from a unique mailbox? Is imap_createmailbox() the only way? Create 10-100k email boxes for every ticket/user??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set up a catch-all mailbox and forward e-mails that are delivered to it to your program. In cPanel: Mail / Default address / Advanced Options / Pipe to a program.

Then read standard input in PHP:

```
$sock = fopen ("php://stdin", 'r');
$email = '';
while (!feof($sock)) {
  $email .= fread($sock, 1024);
}
fclose($sock);
```

Comment: ok thank you, its a 3rd option, which I see very comfortable for receiving  emails.
But what about sending in this way? If I want to send from ID_123456@domain.com , I need a normal mail email box for smtp authentication..

Comment: Most PHP hosting allow for sending mail with the built-in `mail()` command. As for the sender information, use the [`$additional_headers` parameter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php).

Comment: In our company practice, we have been dealing with high spam rating when sending emails with mail() function with no smtp authorization.

According to discussed options, we will try the option of sending emails from a single email adress with SMTP authorization, and then receiving then all and segmenting by the ID in a subject line.

Any other ideas are still welcome ;)

Comment: The choice between mail() and SMTP doesn't affect whether you can put ticket id into the sender address. In both methods, "From: abc@def.com" is only a string of text that you put into the headers.
Please don't forget to mark my answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

I'm developing the same system you are talking about (a CRM). I was studying the possibility of inserting a custom header in emails sent with a ticket ID or similar, but a reply of a customer wouldn't include it. So, currently I'm using the subject to set the ticket ID between tags. When I receive an email (I have a script checking for recent messages) I analyze the subject of mails searching for the ticket ID (and other internal keys for my CRM) and then I start the appropriate process.

I can tell you that is common to use this system in other CRMs.

IMAP is like a terrible headache. Let us know a better solution if you find it!  :)